# How to monitor flow-state / execution status in Spring Integration

Tags: spring-integration

What would be the best practice to monitor state of flow execution?

I'm working on a SI application and our tester guy always complaining that the monitoring of the flow execution is very complex.
You have to check tons of log files to find problems etc.
Best would be to have a database schema where you can detect execution problems, actual state of flow execution, currently executing components.

What do you suggest how to monitor SI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [the framework's JMX Support](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/system-management-chapter.html#jmx-mbean-exporter) to expose channels etc as `MBean`s.

You can monitor channel metrics (sendCounts etc).

You can even use the framework to monitor itself with [JMX channel adapters](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/system-management-chapter.html) to take some action when a condition arises.